# What is the maximum frequency of UILongPressGestureRecognizer' callback function?

Tags: ios, callback, uigesturerecognizer, frequency

I have an issue that when in longpress, move the finger fast, and in the callback function I can not detect the finger has been in an certain area, if you move your finger fast enough. Here is my guess: There is an maximum frequency of the callback function, anybody know the precise number of it?

Comment: What is your issue with long press? Using the UILongPressGestureRecognizer? I think the frequency of observation is high, but that's not what you're asking, right?

Comment: I mean if I move my finger fast enough, I get no callback in rect(200, 200, 200, 200) and when my finger is in point(500, 300), I get a callback. so I can not detect weather I am in a certain area if I move too fast. @Yar

Comment: you're saying that if you move your finger inside the Long Press area too quickly, the Long Press event doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better to use

`touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

`touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

`touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

instead of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?
That functions have much more flexibility rather than gesture recognizer.